# How to remove jQuery event listener on checkbox after it was toggled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following Jquery code

```
$('#filterPageSearchModel_CarMakeFilter').on('change', function () {         
         var make = $(this).val();        
         CreateList(make, '@actionModel', '@idModel');
         CreateList(make, '@actionEngineSize', '@idEngineSize');
         CreateList(make, '@actionSubModel', '@idSubModel');
         CreateList(make, '@actionYear', '@idYear');
         CreateList(make, '@actionMarkOrSeries', '@idMarkOrSeries');         
     });

 var CreateList = function (make, action, id, model, engineSize, submodel) {
        $('.loader').css('display', 'inline');
      //  $(DropDownObject).prop("disabled", true);
        var Make = make;
        var Model = model;
        var Id = id;
        var EngineSize = engineSize;
        var SubModel = submodel;
        $.ajax({
            url: action,
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'JSON',
            data: { Make: Make, Model: Model, EngineSize: EngineSize, SubModel: SubModel },
            success: function (result) {
                $(Id).html('');
                $(Id).append($('<option>Select an Option</option>'));
                $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                    $(Id).append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).html(item.Text));
                });
                $(Id).trigger("chosen:updated");
                $(Id).val(""); // set value to null
                $('.loader').css('display', 'none');
                //$(DropDownObject).prop("disabled", false);
            }
        });
    };
```

I want to be Disable either the function CreateList when a checkbox is ticked or somehow hide/disable the event "onchange" for   "#filterPageSearchModel_CarMakeFilter"
And obviously when the checkbox is not ticked then enable those events again.

Comment: Hide funcionality ?, maybe you mean not to run those functions based on the checkbox state , am i right ?

Comment: Yes you are right. I would like for those events/ functions to no be run when I tick the checkbox

Comment: Use jQuery's `.off('click')` function to remove Click event listeners.

Comment: the event is onchange not Click event. how would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please:

```
$('#filterPageSearchModel_CarMakeFilter').on('change', function (){
    if(!this.checked) {
        var make = $(this).val();        
        CreateList(make, '@actionModel', '@idModel');
        CreateList(make, '@actionEngineSize', '@idEngineSize');
        CreateList(make, '@actionSubModel', '@idSubModel');
        CreateList(make, '@actionYear', '@idYear');
        CreateList(make, '@actionMarkOrSeries', '@idMarkOrSeries'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: `if (!this.checked){ var make = $(this).val(); CreateList(make, '@actionModel', '@idModel');  ...}` is simpler. There is no need for if/else.

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept my answer and up-vote. Good Day!

Comment: I will. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Is there one checkbox or multiple checkboxes? 
Is 'filterPageSearchModel_CarMakeFilter' the checkbox or another checkbox affecting this?

Just grab the checkbox value like this...
`$('#check_id').val();`

so for this one

```
$('#filterPageSearchModel_CarMakeFilter').on('change', function () {
  if ($('#check_id').val()) {    // if checkbox is checked, run the bottom code    
    var make = $(this).val();        
    ...  
  }       
});
```

Comment: The answer provided by Klevin is working for me. Its a single checkbox